# Selecting login/logout pairs in mysql and calculating timespan

Tags: php, mysql, select

I have a table with the following type of login/logout data. I'm trying to create a report of hours worked per day. The first thing I havn't been able to crack is selecting login/logut pairs for a user in mysql and an array containing name, date, timespan.

So for the query I'm looking at:

```
SELECT * FROM timestamps
WHERE name = $namevar
```

Then what do I add to the query to select and add pairs together?

Example Data: ([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e97ec))

```
    id     |      date_time      |    field1    |    field2    |  firstname   |    in_out    |   special
VARCHAR(3) |       DATETIME      | varchar(255) | varchar(255) | varchar(255) | varchar(255) | varchar(255)
-----------+---------------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------
    104    | 2012-06-11 17:14:43 |       2      |       1      | Joshua W     |       O      |      0
    106    | 2012-06-11 17:15:32 |       2      |       1      | Zedfried     |       O      |      0
    215    | 2012-06-11 18:12:14 |       2      |       1      | Chris No     |       O      |      0
    237    | 2012-06-11 18:13:32 |       2      |       1      | Craig St     |       O      |      0
    237    | 2012-06-12 06:49:05 |       2      |       1      | Craig St     |       I      |      0
    026    | 2012-06-12 06:50:32 |       2      |       1      | Renaldo      |       I      |      0
    079    | 2012-06-12 06:50:44 |       2      |       1      | Herman A     |       I      |      0
    104    | 2012-06-12 06:52:44 |       2      |       1      | Joshua W     |       I      |      0
    079    | 2012-06-12 12:28:46 |       2      |       1      | Herman A     |       O      |      0
    079    | 2012-06-12 12:28:53 |       2      |       1      | Herman A     |       I      |      0
    104    | 2012-06-12 12:32:51 |       2      |       1      | Joshua W     |       O      |      0
    104    | 2012-06-12 12:32:59 |       2      |       1      | Joshua W     |       I      |      0
    079    | 2012-06-12 18:19:57 |       2      |       1      | Herman A     |       O      |      0
    104    | 2012-06-12 22:12:25 |       2      |       1      | Joshua W     |       O      |      0
    237    | 2012-06-12 22:12:57 |       2      |       1      | Craig St     |       O      |      0
    079    | 2012-06-13 06:47:21 |       2      |       1      | Herman A     |       I      |      0
```

The final report will look something like this

```
Emp Code    Name    Sun Mon     Tues        Wed     Thurs           Fri     Sat Total           

x 2                 std     OT1 std     OT1 Std     OT1 std     OT1 std     OT1 Std     OT1 std     OT1     OT 2        Grand

AE0001  B SKAKANE   2.25    0   8.75    3    8.75   3    8.75   3    8.75   2    5.00   2   8.75     40.00   21.75   2.25    64.00 
AE006   J MTOLO     8.75         8.75   1    8.75        8.75   1    5.00   5    40.00      7.00     -       47.00 
AE007   B  ZACA     8.75    1    8.75   2    8.75   2    8.75   2                35.00      7.00     -       42.00 
AE0013  C NEHUMBA   8.75         8.75        8.75   1    8.75        5.00   2    40.00      3.00     -       43.00
```

**UPDATE:**

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fabb5/2/1

This solution works in the mysql fiddle above but not in my program:

```
$query = $this -> db -> query('
set @num := 0, @in_out := \'\';

select emp_in.id,
  emp_in.in_time,
  emp_out.out_time
from 
(
  select id, in_out, date_time in_time, 
     @num := if(@in_out = in_out, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
     @in_out := in_out as dummy
  from fingerevent
  where in_out = \'I\'
  order by date_time, id
) emp_in
join
(
  select id, in_out, date_time out_time,
     @num := if(@in_out = in_out, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
     @in_out := in_out as dummy
  from fingerevent
  where in_out = \'O\'
 order by date_time, id
) emp_out
  on emp_in.id = emp_out.id

  and emp_in.row_number = emp_out.row_number
order by emp_in.id, emp_in.in_time

');
```

Error:

```
Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select emp_in.id, emp_in.in_time, emp_out.out_time from ( select id,' at line 3
```

I hope the question is clear. Anything I can clear up, let me know.

Comment: can you provide the structure of your table?

Comment: id varchar(3)
    date date
    field1 varchar(255) 
    field2 varchar(255)
    firstname varchar(255)
    type varchar(255)
    special varchar(255)

Comment: field1, field2 and special are extra unused field from the clock machine.

Comment: Edit table structure into question, please. Not as a comment.

Comment: You have a number of `VARCHAR` fields that would appear to be storing integer data. It would much better to use the appropriate `INT` type for these fields. It also looks like the `type` field would be better converted to a numeric representation - or even a boolean, since there only seems to be 2 possible values. Also your table appears to have no primary key, which is never a good idea. Add an auto-incrementing `INT` field to the table.

Comment: Thanks @DaveRandom. The data is imported from a text file that comes from a biometric clocking machine. Do I change the datatype upon import then?

Comment: @RobinBantjes If the table schema is set up so that the integer columns are an `INT` type, MySQL will convert the types from the raw input data. It looks like `field1`, `field2` and `special` should probably be set to `TINYINT` and `id` is probably best if it is an `INT`.

Comment: @RobinBantjes Is [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef1de/1) anything like what you want? I have made a couple of assumptions, namely: 1) To reduce durations to the nearest 15 minutes (your example report show `8.75`, `2.25` etc) I have rounded down. 2) If there is no "out" entry for a day, assume that the employee clocked out at 23:59:59 on that day. 3) A day with an "out" entry but no "in" entry is ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the table containing the data is called `timestamps`, this query should give you some useful results:

```
SELECT `c`.`day`, `b`.`date`, `b`.`id`, `b`.`firstname`, HOUR(`b`.`duration`) + (FLOOR((MINUTE(`b`.`duration`) / 60) * 4) / 4) AS `hours_worked`
FROM (
  SELECT `a`.`id`, `a`.`firstname`, `a`.`date`, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(`a`.`duration`))) AS `duration`
  FROM (
    SELECT `i`.`id`, `i`.`firstname`, TIMEDIFF(COALESCE(MIN(`o`.`date`), ADDTIME(TIMESTAMP(DATE(MAX(`i`.`date`))), '23:59:59')), MAX(`i`.`date`)) AS `duration`, DATE(`i`.`date`) AS `date`
    FROM `timestamps` `i`
    LEFT JOIN `timestamps` `o`
      ON `i`.`id` = `o`.`id` AND `i`.`type` != `o`.`type` AND DATE(`i`.`date`) = DATE(`i`.`date`) AND `i`.`date` < `o`.`date`
    WHERE `i`.`type` = 'I'
    GROUP BY `i`.`date`
  ) `a`
  GROUP BY `a`.`id`, `a`.`date`
) `b`
JOIN `days` `c`
  ON DAYOFWEEK(`b`.`date`) = `c`.`id`
ORDER BY `b`.`date`, `b`.`id`
```

...where the table `days` is a 1-indexed table of day-of-the-week names starting from Sunday.

If you want to narrow it down to a specific date range, change

```
WHERE i.type = 'I'
```

to

```
WHERE i.type = 'I' AND i.date BETWEEN <startdate> AND <enddate>
```

This query makes 3 assumptions:

- To reduce durations to the nearest 15 minutes (your example report shows `8.75`, `2.25` etc) I have rounded down.
- If there is no `O` entry for a day that has an `I` entry, assume that the employee clocked out at 23:59:59 on that day.
- A day with an `O` entry but no `I` entry is ignored.

[See it working](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ef1de/1)